# calculate time diffrence in mysql by seconds

Tags: mysql

I have two dates 
I want to calculate the diffrence between them 
to copare it with int

as `P_date1 datetime, P_date2 datetime`

```
int a=P_date1 - P_date2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a= TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,P_date1 ,P_date2) .. to minutes


select a= TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,P_date1 ,P_date2)... to seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Use TIMESTAMPDIFF:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, P_date1, P_date2) AS diff FROM .....
```

This function can be used with different time units